# Boolean Difference elements showing up as solid when exporting to Slicer

Tags: modeling, modifiers, 3d-printing, boolean-modifier

When I export a project as an STL file to use in my slicer program ([Chitubox](https://www.chitubox.com/)), any Boolean difference elements I have used in the design show as solid objects.

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

Comment: If you've applied the boolean modifier you can delete the boolean object before exporting it to your slicer program.

Answer (score 1):

As @JohnEason said, if you apply the *Boolean Modifier* before exporting to STL, you could delete the object you've subtracted from the original object since it is no longer needed.

But maybe you didn't even do that since it's not necessary because the option *Apply Modifiers* is enabled by default in the STL Export dialogue, and maybe you want to keep on working non-destructively in Blender and rather not apply the modifier to make changes later on.

For this you can enable the option *Selection Only* in the STL export. With this, only objects you've selected in the viewport will later be part of the STL.

[image: STL export options]

Comment: Thanks for the update. I'm not familiar with the STL exporter so decided that "better safe than sorry" was probably the way to go! :^)

Comment: @JohnEason Actually, I'm not familiar with it either, but something like "selected objects only" is implemented in different export formats so I just guessed it would be there, too ;)

Comment: To be honest I didn't have Blender running at the time so didn't think to look! :^)